# problem in integer multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

The  question mentions that $x$ and $y$ are integers then how it be true that the  multiplication of $xy=8$?

How explanation is right?

Comment: As far as I can see, this whole exercise is a huge nonsense: none of the possibilities, *as explained there*, is an integer (what else?) divisor of $\;8\;$ ...or else they meant to all three possibilities, of course.

Comment: Where did you get this problem from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$D=1, E=2, F=4, G=8, H=-8, I=-4, J=-2, K=-1$ but none of $A, B, C$.

Answer (score 0):

Since **none** of the given values work, the answer is $A$, $B$, and $C$.

Comment: how they are sating that answer is B?

Comment: The answer is B *also*, as you have failed to indicate. The complete answer is *A, B, and C*.

Comment: i guess you are not right.

Comment: The rationale is completely wrong: it says " **The** correct answer is B..." , and this is false, but more interesingly: at the end of it it says "...while the others [24, -16] all divide cleanly into 8"